# Cant authentificate user with FOSUser bundle

Tags: angularjs, symfony, fosuserbundle

I am creating an Angularjs app with Symfony 2.8 on the backend, using FOSUser bundle for the user management.

I have a controller to check the user login and create the user session, but when i try to create the user session symfony returns me this error message:

```
Controller "UserBundle\Controller\LoginController::indexAction()" requires that you provide a value for the "$session" argument (because there is no default value or because there is a non optional argument after this one).
```

There is my controller code:

```
<?php

namespace UserBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\UsernamePasswordToken;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;
use UserBundle\Entity\User;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction(Session $session)
    {
        $arrResult = array('STATUS' => 'ERROR', 'ERROR' => 'INIT', 'DATA' => array() );

        // get post data
        $postData = file_get_contents("php://input");
        $postData = json_decode($postData, TRUE);

        $email      = $postData['email'];
        $password   = $postData['password'];

        if( empty($email) || empty($password) ) 
        {
            $arrResult['ERROR'] = 'ALL_FIELDS_ARE_REQUIRED';
            return new JsonResponse($arrResult);
        }

        $user_manager = $this->get('fos_user.user_manager');
        $factory = $this->get('security.encoder_factory');

        $user = $user_manager->findUserByEmail($email);
        $encoder = $factory->getEncoder($user);
        $salt = $user->getSalt();

        if( $encoder->isPasswordValid($user->getPassword(), $password, $salt) )
        {
            // create user session
            $this->createLoginSession($session, $user);

            $arrResult['DATA'] = array('USERNAME' => $user->getUsername());
            $arrResult['STATUS'] = 'OK';
        }
        else 
        {
            $arrResult['ERROR'] = 'INVALID_CREDENTIALS';
        }

        return new JsonResponse($arrResult);
    }

    private function createLoginSession($session, $objUser)
    {
        $objToken = new UsernamePasswordToken($objUser, null, 'main', $objUser->getRoles() );

        // save token
        $objTokenStorage = $this->get("security.token_storage")->setToken($objToken);
        $session->set( '_security_main', serialize($objToken) );
    }
}
```

What i am doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: why do you use fos user when you make all by hand (and plain wrong btw)
check this repo for some hints. https://github.com/FlyersWeb/angular-symfony

Comment: Thanks. I will check it!

Comment: I have been studying and now i know that the best method to manage auth  on frontend apps is using JWT.